# Spilled drink in PS2. What to do?

Tags: ps2

A couple of days ago a glass of orange juice was spilled and it got into my PS2 through the front ventilation slots. I turned off the power (though no malfunction was evident), unplugged everything and semi-submerged the PS2 in tap water a few times to rinse out the juice. (Distilled water might have been better but it wasn't readily available)

Later I googled how to disassemble the unit (a slimline PAL V12 or V13) and removed the outer plastic case to facilitate drying.

I figure I've done most things right so far but what should I do next?

Should I try to disassemble it further? How long should I wait before trying to power it up again?

Lastly where does the little metal plate go that fell out when I took the case off?

[image]
Its center hole is threaded.

Comment: Serious props and a +1 for a level-headed reaction to a dire situation.

Comment: That is fairly impressive. I wouldn't wait all that long to power it back up, a day or two tops, unless water doesn't evaporate around your place. Heck, if it doesn't work, the worst that happens is you're out 40 bucks.

Comment: If you do get it going again, you might want to install a softmod as a precaution. Look into FreeMCB and OPL - that way, if/when your optical drive breaks (prone to happen, and this accident wont help), you can still play your games.

Answer (score 15):

Because the PS2 is a highly integrated machine, further disassembly will probably do less good than harm.

Depending on how wet you got the thing: To facilitate drying, you can put the unit in a 40°C oven for a while. Think a few hours. A blow dryer might work too, but that is more risky. The point is to get the whole thing warm, not hot, all the way through to help the water evaporate.

If any water got onto the CD-drive assembly, you may have to apply a little bit of silicone grease on the guide rods and spindle. Do not use simple oil, it will harden up and destroy your reader. Rather dont do anything than use the wrong grease.

I would ignore the leftover piece. If it is important, you will notice where it goes.

Comment: Sounds sensible. +1

Answer (score 3):

I know this is creating a Zombie thread but I stumbled upon this whilst looking for the answer to the small metal plate with the threaded hole for my own repair.

Turns out it sits in the bottom end of the upper case for the vertical stand to screw into.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The steps you've taken, and the steps mentioned by Posipiet for drying, are both good.  Rinse the machine with isopropyl alcohol to help cut & remove conductive elements from both the OJ and your tap, and then a final rinse with distilled water.  Dry in a 50C oven for several hours and allow to cool to room temperature before powering up.